# Several Qs regarding Difference between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, dictionary, immutability

I am a bit experienced in Java, but not so familiar with C# and I want to clarify some doubt about C#.

1. Is there any base class or interface like 'Object' in C# ?
2. does '==' operator in c# means "==" in java ?  or "equals()" in java ?
3. if '==' in C# does not means "equals()" in java , how can I override equals() in C# ?
4. Does key in Dictionary of C# should be immutable like java HashMap does? 
   what about "hashcode()" then? is there something similar in c# ?
5. does '+' operator between two different String in C# inefficient like java does?

Comment: Have you even tried to research anything?

Comment: 1) Yes, `System.Object`. But note that value types (which still derive from `Object`) are different from java. 2) Neither. You can overload it. 3) You can override `Equals` like any other virtual method 4) `Equals` and `GetHashCode` must be consistently implemented and should not change while the object is used as a key. Immutability is an easy way to achieve that, but not strictly necessary. 5) yes, it creates a new string copying both old strings.

Comment: Thank you for kind answer, this will help me a lot~

Answer (score 0):

I think "==" means the object is refereed to the same address in the machine. And the equals() means the value of object is the same.